# How to check if mail was send or not using php?

Tags: php, email

How to check if mail was send or not using php ?

I use this code for send email using php. It's work good.

But i want to check email send success or not, How can i do that ?

```
<?PHP
    $to      = "test@mail.com";
    $subject = "test subject";
    $message = "test message";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: SENDER <noreply@sender.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Return-Path: return@sender.com' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@sender.com');
?>
```

Comment: `if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@sender.com')){ echo "Mail has been sent and has done its job."; } else { echo "Sorry Charlie, check your logs.";}` type of thing. ;-)

Comment: You can see if the function succeed, as it returns a bool. However php has no may of knowing what happens after that point.

Comment: RTFM http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: ^ Perfect use of *"RTFM"*